# How to convert TBytes to Binary File? (using MemoryStream)

Tags: delphi, file, binary, stream

How can i convert `Tbytes` type to a `Binary file` using `MemoryStream`?

Comment: "using MemoryStream" is a trap, doubles space requirements

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uwe's answer will work if you have TBytesStream available. If not:

```
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if length(data) > 0 then
      stream.WriteBuffer(data[0], length(data));
    stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Kermia You do realise you have accepted the answer with the worst performance characteristics? @Mason Please don't take offence!

Comment: Title says : `using MemoryStream` and I think I should select the related answer . isn't it?

Comment: @David: For this particular case, yes. But if there's a lot of individual writes instead of just one, especially if they're small ones, you can save a *huge* amount of time by writing everything to a memory stream first and then blockwriting that to a file all at once.

Comment: @Mason Well, I was talking about this particular case. And as for the memory stream, we have this discussion regularly. I have my own classes that deal with that rather better than TMemoryStream to avoid address space fragmentation issues.

Comment: @Kermia I have no problem with which answer you accept. I just want to be sure that you are clear that using `TMemoryStream` is a solution that is slower than necessary. This seemed to be relevant to you when you asked in a comment, "which is faster?"

Comment: @Mason An aside. You have used the wrong write method. You should use `WriteBuffer` instead since it's the one with error checking. I'm sure you know this and this was an oversight.

Answer (score 30):

Or directly with a `TFileStream` to cut down on the number of intermediate objects created:

```
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    if Data <> nil then
      Stream.WriteBuffer(Data[0], Length(Data));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I don't believe using `TMemoryStream` is helpful here since it just involves an extra unnecessary heap allocation/deallocation.

Comment: Thank you David :) . Which one is faster? using `TFileStream` or `TMemoryStream.SaveToFile` ?

Comment: `TMemoryStream.SaveToFile` does its job via a `TFileStream`. Best to cut out the middle man and go straight to `TFileStream`.

Comment: You may consider moving the if-clause outside of the try finally, so the stream will not be created at all if nothing is to write.

Comment: @uwe you'd still need to make an empty file and since this code does that perfectly well I'd be loath to add another test for what is likely a rare corner case.add another test for what is likely a rare corner case.

Answer (score 8):

Well, if answers mention Delphi XE and other streams than `TMemoryStream`, then i suggest one more method.

```
 procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
 begin
   TFile.WriteAllBytes( FileName, Data );
 end;
```

Answer (score 7):

F.I. in Delphi XE:

```
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  stream: TBytesStream;
begin
  stream := TBytesStream.Create(Data);
  try
    stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, but i said : `MemoryStream` . no difference?

Comment: Yes you're right. But I just wanted to see how is it possible.

Comment: A TBytesStream or TMemoryStream creates a TFileStream behind the scenes when you use SaveToFile. It's probably better to just write directly to a TFileStream like David Heffernan shows.

Comment: The whole purpose of my answer was to show that the answer actually lies at your feet when you happen to know the RTL. I didn't care about speed or memory considerations as that was not part of the question. Normally I start optimizing for speed and space when it is necessary.

Comment: @Uwe I don't know `TBytesStream`. Does is copy the data or does it take a reference to it?

Comment: That makes it equivalent to my answer.

Comment: Not quite. It is one TBytesStream instance more that has to be created.

Comment: thanks. It sounds like a useful class. It's an adapter right?

Comment: @David: What Delphi version are you working with? Just checked and TBytesStream is available since D2009.

Comment: @Uwe Yes I've got it on 2010, I just haven't discovered it yet. I only moved up from D6 in the past 12 months.

Comment: @David: Wow, thats what I a call a step! You may still discover some more things. I for myself am usually switching to the newest version when all libraries are available. Sometimes I have to discard one ore the other. Its going quite well as the steps are mostly small and you can concentrate on the new stuff.

Comment: @Uwe Yes it was a big step, but not really all that bad. We couldn't stomach D2005 and D2007, too resource intensive and buggy. We moved to 2010 so that we could get the Unicode port out of the way and be ready to jump to 64 bit as quickly as possible. As I'm sure regular readers of my utterings here know, I'm quite keen on 64 bit!