# Losing data when transfering from Bytes Buffer to AnsiString

Tags: string, sockets, delphi, tcp, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to send a 4063 bytes AMR file (just for testing) from my CentOS VPS

```
nc IP 45500 < sample.amr
```

But when the application receives it just show a cutted data:

```
1448: #!AMR-WB
Ô_Æ ÅÑ¤m^8E•Ì^^ìÖõ¾_€°

2617:
```

The strange thing is: If I edit the AMR file and remove the marked char:

[image]

And send again the same AMR file I receive:

```
1448: #!AMR-WB
Ô_Æ ÅÑ¤m^8E•Ì^^ìÖõ¾_€°ÀžH¯ë2Çc oÚÖÉ¾øy$Ý

2616: ¢Khw^è“Êº\?¬šJ£<é<'
```

.. more data, specifically up to the next NUL char

[image]

This is the code for my Socket `onClientRead`

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  received,a: string;
  size,i: Integer;
  AnsiStr: String;
  Bytes: array[0..2048*256] of Byte;
begin

  Size := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  Socket.ReceiveBuf(Bytes[0], Size);

  SetString(AnsiStr, PAnsiChar(@Bytes[0]), Size);
  received := IntToStr(Size)+': '+AnsiStr;

  Memo1.Lines.Add(received);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
end;
```

I believe the `SetString` command is causing this, but not sure how to receive the whole DATA. I just want to receive the whole file and copy it to a new AMR file on my side.

Extra:
The file that I am trying to send from my server to my computer is located here:
http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.amr

Comment: Which Delphi version? Can you show the original content sent?

Comment: If this is a version 2009 or later, your string is a UnicodeString. That should not work. Anyway, strings should not be used to store binary data. That has always been a bad idea.

Comment: Is this data text or binary? If it is text, what is the encoding? If it is binary, don't use strings to hold it.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.PAnsiChar) for `PAnsiChar`, this should explain your problem: `Defines a null-terminated ANSI string.` Do not load binary data in any kind of string

Comment: I am using Delphi Berlin, I tried UnicodeString but I receives chinese characters. I added the AMR file that I am using, is a 4kb file. I don't know what to do to acomplish this.

Comment: You can receive the **data** just fine. Your problem is that you think you can *display that data* as a string, and you can't (because it is not character data). You can't use a string for anything but string content. IOW, stop trying to pretend binary data is text. It's not text. Don't transfer binary (non-text) data into AnsiString in the first place. It's bytes, not chars.

Comment: So what can I do instead of store it on a string variable? I just want to receive the data and create the AMR file on my side

Comment: You have the data, in `Bytes`. It's already there. Save the `Bytes` content to a file. You're done. No string of any kind involved. Use a `TFileStream` and write the contents of the `Bytes` array to it. Your problem is you're trying to write **binary data** to a **text control** (a TMemo), and it's **not text**.

Comment: I tried yesterday to save the byte array into a file, but the file is not the same as the original, I was using the code in the first answer of this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445089/how-to-convert-tbytes-to-binary-file-using-memorystream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445089/how-to-convert-tbytes-to-binary-file-using-memorystream)

Comment: The accepted answer at that question works, but is very poor. Pointless to copy the in memory byte array to a memory stream and then save to disk. Save directly to disk. Use the answer I gave. And please do not ever out binary data into a string. Ever.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used your answer but I had to convert from Bytes Array to TBytes and now I have a file with 256KB full of null character; And same result if I write from the Bytes array too

Comment: So do some debugging. You can see your code. We can't.

Comment: I tried sending parts of that AMR file, some parts are received well other parts no, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Debug. Check that you have received the entire file. Make sure that you can save a byte array to disk reliably. If what is saved isn't what you expect, then the byte array doesn't contain what you expect. You need to learn how to debug.

Comment: @Martin: TBytes is a byte array already (finally, it resolves to `array of Byte`). What did you convert? And how did you write the array? I hope you did not do something like `Stream.Write(TheArray, Length(TheArray));`? If so, rather do `Stream.Write(TheArray[0], Length(TheArray));`.

Comment: @Rudy Should be WriteBuffer rather than Write. Otherwise you need to add error checking on return value.

Comment: @David: yes, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main reasons why your code doesn't work:

- you are using a Unicode version of Delphi, so the `string` type maps to `UnicodeString`, instead of `AnsiString` like you are expecting.
- internally, the `TMemo.Lines.Add()` method passes the string to the `TMemo` window using the [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633.aspx) message, which treats the input string as null-terminated. That is why your file content gets truncated at `nul` "characters".

As other people said in comments, you are trying to display binary data as if it were text, but it is not text.  Save the raw binary data as-is to an actual file on your HDD instead.  If you want to display the file bytes in your UI, display them in a text-safe format, such as hex.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Socket.Data := TFileStream.Create('<some path>\sample.amr', fmCreate);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  TFileStream(Socket.Data).Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Size: Integer;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  Received: string;
begin
  Size := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  if Size < 1 then Exit;

  SetLength(Bytes, Size);
  Size := Socket.ReceiveBuf(Bytes[0], Size);
  if Size < 1 then Exit;

  TFileStream(Socket.Data).WriteBuffer(Bytes[0], Size);

  SetLength(Received, Size*2);
  BinToHex(Bytes[0], PChar(Received), Size);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Size) + ': ' + Received);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, this works very well, but how could be possible to make a condition for create the AMR file, I do like to receive short messages and that AMR file, but I would not like to create the file each time that I receive a "Hello" message. So how can we conditionate the creation of that file?

Comment: @MartinOcandoCorleone: That's a different question. Remy answered the one you asked here. If you now have another question, you'll have to create a new post using the *Ask Question* button and ask there.

Comment: @MartinOcandoCorleone your `nc` example just dumps the `.amr` file as-is to the TCP connection and then closes the connection, there is no protocol involved. What you are asking for requires you to implement a protocol. The client needs to send a command informing the server that it wants to upload a file, including its name and size. The server can then create the file and reply back that it is OK to receive. Only then can the client send the bytes.  Implementing a protocol is a very broad topic. If you have trouble implementing it, ask new questions about that as needed.

Comment: @MartinOcandoCorleone  I don't recommend using `TServerSocket` for this, though. Although it can be done, it is a lot of extra work to implement the necessary buffering and command/response handling with it. `TServerSocket` is just a bare-boned TCP wrapper, you would have to implement all of the higher level logic manually.  You are better off using a 3rd party server, such as Indy's `TIdTCPServer`, which has built-in support for handling such higher level logics for you.